# Is it  possible to create a folder in iBooks?

Tags: ipad, ipod-touch, pdf, books

I have iPad and iPod touch. Both I bought just for reading books in pdf format.

If it is possible, I want to create some folders to separate the books based on categories I will define.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as long as you're running the latest version.

1. Tap the button a the top of the bookshelf where it likely says "**Books**" (though it might say "**PDFs**") -- this is the **Collections** button.
2. Tap "**New**" to add a new collections folder with a name of your choice.
3. Tap the "**Books**" collection and you'll see all of your books.
4. Tap the "**Select**" button in the upper-right corner, then tap on all of the books you want to move into a collection.
5. Tap "**Move**" and select the collection you want to move the books into.

Poof, they're now out of the default "Books" collection and now in the collection you chose.

Comment: Tried this for the first time yesterday, shame that it works nowheres near as well as arranging app icons in folders.

Comment: @bpapa Agreed, it's not at all intuitive and is a lot more work than it needs to be. Happy to no longer have to scroll through every single book and PDF on my device, though, and glad that it syncs across devices (via iTunes, not over the air, though).

Comment: If you use iCloud in Books then all content - collections and books - are synced over the air.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the latest iBooks it is possible to create your own categories of books. When in your iBooks library on the iPod, tap the middle button at the top, it will probable read Books or PDFs, to create/edit your categories. The same functionality is found by tapping the Categories button on the iPad iBooks.

Once you have the categories you want, you can move books into them by tapping the Edit button in the library view, tapping the books to select them and then tap the Move button. Select the category you want, and press done.

You can then switch between categories from the same screen that you created them.